# How to add hover and mouse click effect on ImageList in Material UI v5.11.11

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, hover

I've created a list of images using MaterialUI now I want to add mouse hover effect to highlight the image under mouse cursor. Below is my code for the image list. How do I achieve this?

```
<Box
        sx={{
          height: 450,
          marginLeft: "10em",
          backgroundColor: "white",
          display: "grid",
          gridTemplateColumns: {
            mobile: "repeat(1, 1fr)",
            bigMobile: "repeat(2, 1fr)",
            tablet: "repeat(3, 1fr)",
            desktop: "repeat(4, 1fr)",
          },
          [`& .${imageListItemClasses.root}`]: {
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
          }
        }}
      >
        <ImageList
          variant="quilted"
          sx={{ width: 2000, height: 1000, margin: "5em" }}
          cols={3}
          rowHeight={500}
          
        >
          {cardsList.map((item, index) => (
            <div>
              <ImageListItem key={index}>
                <img
                  src={"data:image/jpeg;base64," + item.content}
                  alt={item.fileName}
                />
              </ImageListItem>
            </div>
          ))}
        </ImageList>
      </Box>
```

Answer (score 2):

Changed ImageListItem to a custom one with hover style as per below ..though I personally dislike the new way of styling element in MUI v5.11

```
const ImageListItemWithStyle = styled(ImageListItem)(({ theme }) => ({
    "&:hover": {
      cursor: "pointer",
      opacity: 0.8,
      border: `solid 5px red`,
      //boxShadow: `5px 10px ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
      
    },
  }));

 <ImageListItemWithStyle key={index} >
                <img
                  src={"data:image/jpeg;base64," + item.content}
                  alt={item.fileName} 
                  id={index}
                  onClick={cardSelected}
                />
              </ImageListItemWithStyle>
```